# What is the best way to create a 'list' associated with a model?

Tags: python, django

I want to be able to associate a company name in my models with a list of 'milestone' percentage points, in order to calculate how far each company is from the nearest milestone.

For example:

```
List_Of_Milestones = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25]
Current_Progress = 9.5%
```

Example Output = "Company A is 0.5% away from the 10% milestone, and 4.5% above the 5% milestone."

The logic is simple from a Python standpoint, but I can't get my brain around how I would create this in a model setup and allow the user to set their own list of milestones.

Answer (score 0):

I would start off with two models: `Company` and `Milestone`.

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Milestone(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description = models.TextField()
    percentage = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=1)


class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    milestone_progress = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=1)

    @property
    def milestone_status(self):
        try:
            next_milestone = self.milestone_set.filter(percentage__gt=milestone_progress).order_by('percentage').first()
            return "This company is {} away from their next milestone".format(next_milestone.percentage-self.milestone_progress)
        except:
            return None
```

A foreign key relationship is build between these two models, which allows a company to have many milestones.

By utilising a 'proxy' field within the `Company` model, you can retrieve all milestones for a given company and compare it against the company's `milestone_progress` field.

Finally by subtracting the `next_milestone` percentage value from progress it will return the delta. This is then factored into a simple example string but you may want to configure this to suit your own presentation requirements.

Comment: Apologies for the late response to this.

All look to make sense to me except the 'self.milestones_set' - What is that referring to?

Comment: No problem, sorry it should be `self.milestone_set` not `self.milestones_set`. This returns the reverse of the foreign key so all related `Milestone` objects for that particular instance.